# Determine if string starts with letters A through I

Tags: java, letter, startswith

I've got a simple java assignment. I need to determine if a string starts with the letter A through I. I know i have to use string.startsWith(); but I don't want to write, `if(string.startsWith("a"));` all the way to I, it seems in efficient. Should I be using a loop of some sort?

Comment: Upper case? Lower case? Either?

Comment: If you'll need to match both upper case and lower case characters, check out my post. Mark Byers matches only uppercase and we have a few  posts matching lower case, just pick one (and update your question-post to clarify which one it is that you want).

Answer (score 37):

You don't need regular expressions for this.

Try this, assuming you want uppercase only:

```
char c = string.charAt(0);
if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'I') { ... }
```

If you do want a regex solution however, you can use this ([ideone](http://ideone.com/qlwCj)):

```
if (string.matches("^[A-I].*$")) { ... }
```

Comment: Okay, this worked. but what exactly does the ^ mean, and .*$ mean? I know the [a-i] means a through i

Comment: i mean, im asking what the ^ and .*$ means, and why i need it. I like to understand everything, as we haven't learned this in my computer science class yet

Comment: @Archey The  means start of string, the . means any character, * means any number of times and $ is end of line. So, basically start of line followed by A-I followed by any character 0 or more times until the end of line.

Comment: @Archey you can accept his answer if you want by clicking the check mark next to the two up and down arrows

Answer (score 3):

```
if ( string.charAt(0) >= 'A' && string.charAt(0) <= 'I' )
{
}
```

should do it

Answer (score 3):

How about this for brevity?

```
if (0 <= "ABCDEFGHI".indexOf(string.charAt(0))) {
    // string starts with a character between 'A' and 'I' inclusive
}
```

Comment: Reasonable, now put it into a method and make A and I parameters.

Comment: The above condition is filled, indexOf will return a value greater than -1 if the first character is found within the string. Right now it will act as if all letters accept BCDEGHI is correct.

Comment: @Bill, this method obviously isn't the best solution for a range check, for a set of characters, like "AEOIU", it works quite well.

Comment: @refp, I think you will find the code correct including the `'A'`, `(0 <= 0) == true` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
string.charAt(0) >= 'a' && string.charAt(0) <= 'j'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char c=string.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
if( c >= 'a' && c <= 'i' )
    ...
```

This makes it easy to extract it as a method:

```
public static boolean startsBetween(String s, char lowest, char highest) {
    char c=s.charAt(0);
    c=Character.toLowerCase(c);  //thx refp
    return c >= lowest && c <= highest;
}
```

which is HIGHLY preferred to any inline solution.  For the win, tag it as final so java inlines it for you and gives you better performance than a coded-inline solution as well.

Comment: you shouldn't be lowercasing the entire string, check out how I solved it in my post, yes.. I know; premature optimization ;-)

Comment: You are correct, it also copies the whole thing.  As long as it's broken out into a method, might as well take the step to break it out into it's own variable.

Answer (score 0):

if ( string.toUpperCase().charAt(0) >= 'A' && string.toUpperCase().charAt(0) <= 'I' )

should be the easiest version...