# How to make program display an error message if the input doesn't start with a letter

Tags: java

Just like what the title says i have been trying to do this for hours.

```
System.out.print ("Please input the first name: ");
name1 = in.next();

if (name1.substring(0,1).equals("[a-zA-Z]"))
System.out.println("\t" + name1.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+name1.substring(1).toLowerCase() + "  is in the name list");

else if (name1.substring(0,1).equals("[0-9]"));
System.out.println("error");
```

This is part of the code that is not working out for me.
I dont really know where i went wrong im a beginner at this.
With this code whatever I write i get the second System.out.println back which is error. I want the program to display an error message if the string doesnt start with a number. Also, please use the if statement to do that because I couldn't use something I have not covered otherwise I would have searched it.

Comment: What do you think `equals("a-zA-Z")` does and why do you think so?

Comment: Indeed. `equals` is not a regex match.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that is the last thing I used after using "contains" thinking it is the same as contains.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a string starts with one of several prefixes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790584/how-to-check-if-a-string-starts-with-one-of-several-prefixes)

Comment: @Tarik:  Going to have to disagree on that dupe there.  This is only checking a single letter after all; there are better ways to do it.

Comment: @Makoto in that case it's duplicate to that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540015/determine-if-string-starts-with-letters-a-through-i

Comment: @Tarik - That's not a duplicate. They are looking for specific letters. The OP is asking for any letter

Comment: If trying to decide between `Character.isAlphabetic` versus `Character.isLetter`, check out the post about [the difference between them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304804/what-is-the-difference-between-character-isalphabetic-and-character-isletter-in) for TL;DR, if it's always English, it doesn't matter :-)

Comment: @Tarik:  It's *slightly* stronger, but I'm not seeing it as a dupe to this one at all for reasons already elaborated on by Ascalonian.

Comment: Yes you have absolutly right Mokoto and Ascalonian on that, and my apologizes to the OP, I can't see how to remove that flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `matches` if you want to use REGEX:

```
if (name1.substring(0,1).matches("[a-zA-Z]"))
```

equals checks for exact match. It will only be true if your first letter is "[a-zA-Z]" which will never happen.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply I also forgot to ask if it was possible to ignore the input if it did not start with a letter. I would appreciate it if you helped me in that.

Comment: @Abz Just saw your message. You can do anything you want to the input including "ignoring" it. But you still need to receive the input with a variable first, else there is no way to check whether the first letter is a letter.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
if(!Character.isAlphabetic(name1.charAt(0)) {
    //it's not a letter
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use [`Character.isLetter(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29), name your variables and define them when you initialize them. Something like

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print ("Please input the first name: ");
String firstName = in.next();
if (Character.isLetter(firstName.charAt(0))) {
    // It is a letter.
} else {
    // It is not a letter.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get the second print statement all the time is because you've added a ';' after the else if:

Change

```
else if (name1.substring(0,1).equals("[0-9]"));
```

To

```
else if (name1.substring(0,1).equals("[0-9]"))
```

Remove that semi colon first!

Comment: This is syntax suggestion, you could have added it in comments rather then an answer. This does not solve the problem even though.

Comment: True. But I think my answer does explain why he was getting "error" printed regardless of whatever he gave as an input, which is stated as part of the question.